# Problema no Textbox do XAML para o XAML.cs

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox

Tenho um XAML (Cadastro.xaml) onde fiz um `TextBox` e um `PasswordBox` e nomeei eles como `txtCpf` e `txtSenha`, até então sem nenhum problema.

Quando eu vou usar eles no `Cadastro.xaml.cs`, eu não consigo e aparece o erro falando que:

> "o nome não existe no contexto atual"

Como eu faço declarar no `.cs` as duas `TextBox`?

Comment: Aconteceu cmg, eu só reinicia o VS.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez tenha declarado os componentes de forma errada.

Abaixo segue a forma correta de nomear seus componentes, utilizando a propriedade `x:Name`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtCpf" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
<PasswordBox x:Name="txtSenha" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

E no código você consegue acessá-los da seguinte forma:

```
string cpg = txtCpf.Text;
string password = txtSenha.Password;
```

Comment: O problema tava no "x:Name="txtCpf"". Não tinha isso no meu. Valeu, cara!!!

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou, marque ela como correta para ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema!